# Opposite of org-ellipses

Tags: org-mode

I currently have `org-ellipses` be a down caret. Is it possible to have an up caret when a header is expanded? I haven't been able to find any relevant org-mode settings.

Comment: There is a variable `org-ellipsis` (singular, as opposed to plural ellipses). Is that what you meant? As far as I know, when the header is expanded, no ellipsis is shown in any case, so I'm afraid you're out of luck (if I understood you correctly).